# how to drop multiple (~5000) columns in the pandas dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 5632 columns, and I only want to keep 500 of them. I have the columns names (that I wanna keep) in a dataframe as well, with the names as the row index. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Probably just use `.loc`: `df.loc[:, df1.index]`, but please provide a [mcve] so we can provide a suitable answer. It doesn't need to be all 5000+ columns, an example with say 10 will probably suffice.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation)

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume your DataFrame is named as `df` and you have a list `cols` of column indices you want to retain. Then you should use:

`df1 = df.iloc[:, cols]`

This statement will drop all the columns other than the ones whose indices have been specified in `cols`. Use `df1` as your new DataFrame.